# How to serialize a python class to pass onto javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass a variable onto a javascript in flask.
But I get the following error: `TypeError: Object of type MyClass is not JSON serializable`

Code:

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    data = {
        "foo": myObj
    }
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

To note that `myObj` is a custom class object of type MyClass.

index.html:

```
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='my_script.js', type="module") }}" crossorigin="anonymous"
            defer>
    </script>
    <script>
        let data = {{ data|tojson }};
    </script>
```

my_script.js:

```
console.log(data);
```

I tried to simply write `{{ data }}` instead of `{{ data|tojson }}` but I get the errors:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'` and `my_script.js?type=module:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at my_script.js?type=module:1`

I know that there are a lot of question, but I do not find one that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to pass a Python object to Javascript. It's not going to work. The best thing to do is convert it to JSON, which is compatible between Python and Javascript.

Using the `json` module you can serialise your dictionary. However, the Python object of `MyClass` is not JSON serialisable. You should be able to serialise the `__data__` attribute instead, which is a dictionary of attributes in the object.

Change your Python like this:

```
import json

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    data = {
        "foo": myObj.__dict__
    }
    return render_template('index.html', data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Indeed, it worked. I did not know that i should pass it as string and that should be mentioned is that in the javascript one should reassemble the json if needed as object. ```data = JSON.parse(data)```  in my case.